# Schema inheritance with propel1.5

Tags: php, propel

I have developed my little own framework, which depends on some model classes. I am using the framework on different projects, but with side effect that project-related changes in the framework are not committed to one "single" framework code, but the changes lost for the other projects.

Now I want to outsource the framework code to one single place and symlink in my projects to that code. So that I am using one model in the framework I have a schema.xml for the framework. In the projects I need also schema.xml files for project-related models. In one project I need to extend generated classes of the framework model.

Is there a way to extend a schema.xml file, so that the propel_generator can generate correct sql file and model classes?
Or is there any workaround / better way for such issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you could use the `<external-schema>` element and split your schema into the "common" part and the "project specific" part (containing an `<external-schema>` element pointing to the "common" schema).

See Propel doc : http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/Schema#external-schemaelement

Comment: Yes i was playing around some time with this feature but it is not a satisfying solution for me. In my opinion a big problem is that I want to fix the code of the peer classes, but this will not be possible by using the external schema method.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "fixing the code of the peer classes" ?

Comment: I mean to write the code of the e.g. UserPeer class once and then it is fixed for all projects. But as I wrote I will use an application model to prevent code duplication.

Comment: I think that I begin to understand... For example, you want to define a **User** class in your framework's `schema.xml`, and you want to add some project-specific fields to that **User** class ? I guess that if you try to define a single table in two parts (one in the framework's `schema.xml`, the other in the project's `schema.xml`), it doesn't works ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a leck of understanding of the terminology "domain models". I wanted to use the models created by propel not only as domain model but also as application model. But this would be wrong. 
I will use the `<external-schema>` feature to divide my domain model into different parts, but I need to create a "application model" layer to encapsulate the domain model from the rest of the world ;)